# Iniciar uma ferramenta de linha de comando em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Como posso criar uma ferramenta de linha de comando em Python, que funcione como  ao `ls` do Linux ou `dir` do Windows?

Como eu faria para iniciar um *script* como esse que, mais tarde, será compilado como um executável?

Comment: Olá! Você deseja iniciar uma ferramenta de linha de comando **escrita** em python por outro executável python?

Comment: não nesse momento nesse momento minha ideia e de fazer uma ferramenta para checar se certos arquivos existem em um diretório desejado por exemplo: `checar_se_existe -file lista.txt`

Comment: recomendo editar a pergunta para deixa-la mais clara, da forma como está, parece que a pergunta é como usar o `ls` de dentro do python e não como implementar o seu próprio `ls``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo comentário o que você está procurando são funções para simular o comportamento do `ls` ou do `dir` correto? sendo assim, lhe recomendo olhar o comando [os.listdir](http://os.listdir) para listar os arquivos de um diretório, o módulo [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) par verificar dentre os itens do `listdir` oq é um arquivo (`os.path.isfile`) ou oq é um diretório (`os.path.isdir`) e a função [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) para retornar os atributos de um arquivo.

```
>>> import os
>>> files = os.listdir()
>>> files
['foo.txt']
>>> os.path.isfile(files[0])
True
>>> os.stat(files[0])
os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=30049365, st_dev=16777218, st_nlink=1, st_uid=501, st_gid=20, st_size=4, st_atime=1470085341, st_mtime=1470085341, st_ctime=1470085341)
```

Sobre a parte de criar uma ferramenta de command-line, você deve pesquisar sobre [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), um exemplo bem simples seria:

```
import argparse
import os


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='ls clone')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

ls_parser = subparsers.add_parser(
    'ls', help='lista os arquivos e diretórios do diretório atual'
)
ls_parser.set_defaults(command='ls')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.command == 'ls':
        print(os.listdir())
```

Para utilizar esse script seria algo como

```
$ python3 foo.py ls
['foo.txt']
```

Comment: Se for isso que ele quer fazer mesmo, o `os.listdir()` resolve! +1

Comment: foi oq eu entendi na conversa dentro dos comentários da pergunta, inclusive sugeri editar a pergunta para torna-la mais clara

Comment: Ficou bacana o código com `argparse`.

Comment: vlw @zekk o argparse é bem bacana, apesar de existirem algumas libs para facilitar eu acho simples o suficiente.

Answer (score 3):

Para executar um comando externo use o módulo [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

Ou usando o método [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system):

```
import os

os.system("ls -l")
```

**Edição**: Use [`sys.platform:`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.platform) para verificar o sistema operacional e executar os comandos de acordo com o sistema:

```
import sys, subprocess

def main():
    if sys.platform == "linux":
        subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
    elif sys.platform == "darwin":
        subprocess.call("ls")
    elif sys.platform == "win32":
        subprocess.call("dir")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```